# What elements are common to Shiner Bock and Real Ale's Fireman's #4?

Tags: beer, ingredients

Shiner Bock and Fireman's #4 both have this weird aftertaste that I can't stand. Any idea what they both have in common so I can avoid it?

EDIT: It's almost a slimy taste (I know slimy is not a taste, but that's the best way I can describe it). I'm starting to associate it with most lagers. Also Mexican beer. I think it might be a Texas summer heat thing.

Comment: Can you describe the flavor?

Comment: So its more of a mouthfeel thing.  But mexican beers??? Like corona, model and dos equis??? Those beers seem pretty crisp and dry to me...to keep using mouthfeel terminology.

Comment: Take one dos equis (in a clear bottle), wrap it completely in aluminum foil, and set it in a window sill.  Take another dos equis, not wrapped, and set it next to the first one.  Wait a day or two.  Refrigerate both.  Do a side-by-side taste test.  Then answer your own question.

Comment: Are you comparing the bottled varieties or draft?  I've found Fireman's is very inconsistent on draft, and does sometimes have an unpleasant aftertaste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't stand the taste of a bock and an ale.  So, it's not the yeast that you don't like, but that's about all one can say base on the information you've provided.  Shiner bock gets clobbered on beer advocate.  Fireman's comes through ok, though.  It's probably just that beer has been mistreated.  Like you say, a Texas summer issue.  The suggestion would be to find a beer seller that's got the freshest stock.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure. Shiner Bock is a ghettoized lager. A bock is a strong German lager, but if you've ever had Shiner Bock you know that's something a bit different... Fireman #4 is a blonde ale. I'm with baka, can you give us a description of this aftertaste?